# Let $f: G \to G' $ be a group homomorphism. Show that the pre-image of $h \in G' $is not a subgroup of $G$ unless $h$ is the neutral element in $G'$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The set $f^{-1}(h)$ is not always a subgroup of $G$.

Why is this true?  It seems like the inverse of an image should be in G and retain all the properties of a group.

Comment: Hint:  any subgroup of $G$ must contain the identity element of $G$.

Comment: Ok! I was thinking about this all wrong.  "The set" here is referring to the set created by one particular h in G'.  h should not necessarily map to the identity element unless it's preimage is in the kernel of f.

Comment: Not following.  $h$ is in the image of $f$.  The pre-image, $f^{-1}(h)$, consists of all $g\in G$ such that $f(g)=h$.  Now, since $f$ is a homomorphism we must have $f(e_G)=e_{G'}$ (Where the $e's$ denote the respective identity elements).  Thus, if $h\neq e_{G'}$ it can't happen that $f(e_G)=h$.

Comment: Lol, thanks.  That's what I was basically thinking but didn't word it well.